# Refused to execute "ngrok link" as script because "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff" was given and its Content-Type is not a script MIME type

Tags: reactjs, safari, salesforce, ngrok, browserstack

I am using ngrok to create a link for my localhost and using it in my vf page and it is working in Chrome, Edge and other browsers. Now I am testing it in broswerStack Safari but it giving issues

```bash
[Error] Refused to execute https://99.ngrok-free.app/dist/builder.mui.dev.js as script because "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff" was given and its Content-Type is not a script MIME type.
[Error] Did not parse stylesheet at 'https://99.ngrok-free.app/dist/builder.mui.css' because non CSS MIME types are not allowed in strict mode.
```

Can anybody tell me why it is happening?

I don't know from where to start

Comment: is it working fine when you are executing the test on your local safari browser?

Comment: No , it is giving issue in my local safari browser